# Zurb foundation 6 align-right not working

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

Is align-right deprecated in Zurb Foundation 6?

```
    <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x align-right">
      <div class="medium-4 cell">Our Content</div> 
      <div class="medium-4 cell">More Content j</div> 
    </div>
```

is not aligning the cells to the right,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it works as expected here: https://codepen.io/rafibomb/pen/QzwGYO

If you want the cells to shrink, you can add the `.shrink` class to each cell instead of medium-4

Make sure you have the XY grid enabled in app.scss as well as 
`@include foundation-flex-classes;`